# colorbar find the width of color segment

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I have a color bar which has several blocks of colors. How can I find the width of each color segment so I can then print that out somewhere else.
I've tried mouseevent.ydata etc but that only outputs where you have clicked. Is there a method that can get the width of the color segement?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want the display width (in pixels), or the value width (as in the mapping from color to the represented value)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modified example of one of the demos from the matplotlib site, it also prints out the paths that draw the colorbar.

Using `iPython` and its handy autocomplete you can find out the members of a class;

```
cb.[Press Tab]
cb.add_checker        cb.extend             cb.set_cmap
cb.add_lines          cb.filled             cb.set_colorbar
cb.alpha              cb.formatter          cb.set_label
cb.autoscale          cb.get_array          cb.set_norm
cb.autoscale_None     cb.get_clim           cb.set_ticklabels
cb.ax                 cb.get_cmap           cb.set_ticks
cb.boundaries         cb.lines              cb.solids
cb.callbacksSM        cb.locator            cb.spacing
cb.changed            cb.mappable           cb.to_rgba
cb.check_update       cb.norm               cb.update_bruteforce
cb.cmap               cb.orientation        cb.update_dict
cb.colorbar           cb.outline            cb.update_normal
cb.config_axis        cb.patch              cb.update_ticks
cb.dividers           cb.set_alpha          cb.values
cb.draw_all           cb.set_array          cb.vmax
cb.drawedges          cb.set_clim           cb.vmin
```

So i just tried a load of these. `solids` seemed the most promising.

```
In [53]: print cb.solids
<matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh object at 0xb1a620c>
```

Then i just looked in the [documentation for Quadmesh](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html?highlight=quadmesh#matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh), and found something that seemed promising.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Use a pcolor or imshow with a custom colormap to make a contour plot.

Since this example was initially written, a proper contour routine was
added to matplotlib - see contour_demo.py and
http://matplotlib.sf.net/matplotlib.pylab.html#-contour.
"""

from pylab import *


delta = 0.01
x = arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
X,Y = meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
Z = Z2 - Z1 # difference of Gaussians

cmap = cm.get_cmap('PiYG', 11)    # 11 discrete colors

im = imshow(Z, cmap=cmap, interpolation='bilinear',
            vmax=abs(Z).max(), vmin=-abs(Z).max())
#axis('off')
cb = colorbar()

for path in cb.solids.get_paths():
    print path

show()
```

[image]

and then the terminal output:

```
Path([[ 0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.          0.        ]
 [ 1.          0.09090909]
 [ 0.          0.09090909]
 [ 0.          0.        ]], None)
Path([[ 0.          0.09090909]
 [ 1.          0.09090909]
 [ 1.          0.18181818]
 [ 0.          0.18181818]
 [ 0.          0.09090909]], None)
Path([[ 0.          0.18181818]
 [ 1.          0.18181818]
 [ 1.          0.27272727]
 [ 0.          0.27272727]
 [ 0.          0.18181818]], None)
Path([[ 0.          0.27272727]
 [ 1.          0.27272727]
 [ 1.          0.36363636]
 [ 0.          0.36363636]
 [ 0.          0.27272727]], None)
Path([[ 0.          0.36363636]
 [ 1.          0.36363636]
 [ 1.          0.45454545]
 [ 0.          0.45454545]
 [ 0.          0.36363636]], None)
Path([[ 0.          0.45454545]
 [ 1.          0.45454545]
 [ 1.          0.54545455]
 [ 0.          0.54545455]
 [ 0.          0.45454545]], None)
Path([[ 0.          0.54545455]
 [ 1.          0.54545455]
 [ 1.          0.63636364]
 [ 0.          0.63636364]
 [ 0.          0.54545455]], None)
Path([[ 0.          0.63636364]
 [ 1.          0.63636364]
 [ 1.          0.72727273]
 [ 0.          0.72727273]
 [ 0.          0.63636364]], None)
Path([[ 0.          0.72727273]
 [ 1.          0.72727273]
 [ 1.          0.81818182]
 [ 0.          0.81818182]
 [ 0.          0.72727273]], None)
Path([[ 0.          0.81818182]
 [ 1.          0.81818182]
 [ 1.          0.90909091]
 [ 0.          0.90909091]
 [ 0.          0.81818182]], None)
Path([[ 0.          0.90909091]
 [ 1.          0.90909091]
 [ 1.          1.        ]
 [ 0.          1.        ]
 [ 0.          0.90909091]], None)
```

I don't know what coordinate space these numbers are on though. Sorry.